# PCLint "This file requires compiler and library support" error

Tags: c++, c++11, pc-lint

I've been trying to get run PC-Lint and through various tries it still gives me this error

```
<issue desc="#error This file requires compiler and library support \" .... file= "arm_gcc_none_eabi_5.3.1\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\5.3.1\bits\c++0x_warning.h"/>
```

I know the issue is tied to the C++ standard, but I have no idea how to fix it in pclint. I tried the  `-std=c++11` equivalent `-A(C++11)` but the error persisted.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: since this question is about `C++` and not about `C` (they are two different languages)  Please remove the `c` tag from the question

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: The issue is that this is related to my work so I'm not really sure how much of it I can share. When I'm running the pclint I link some premade options that we already have and that are used on different project successfully. 

This issue is raised from files that are inside the compiler. The `c++0x_warning.h` contains a define, that requires that the c++ standard is at least c++11.

The only question is basically how to enable it pclint.

Comment: @wheeeper: That's why we want a **minimal** example. If it contains work-related stuff, it's not minimal.